# Vim — running external command bound to F5 inserts result in source

Tags: vim, command-line, macvim

I'm currently developing a webapp that need a "compilation" phase to be tested. For this, I have a simple shell script, which is designed to run from a precise directory.

So in Vim, when I enter command mode and issue this, it works:

```
:lcd /my/script/directory
:!./build debug
```

My build script writes some logs in the command window, everything is fine, and tells me to press return to go back editing my stuff. Fine.

Now I'd like to bind this to `F5` to speed things up. In my `~/.vimrc`, I have added this:

```
map <F5> :lcd /my/script/directory<CR>! ./build debug<CR>
```

But after source'ing my `~/.vimrc`, when I press F5, my script runs correctly... but strangely Vim replaces the current line I'm on with the output of the script. The same if I do `map <silent> <F5> …`

If i change `./build debug` with a simple `ls`, the problem arises too. The output of the `ls` is inserted in my current document, overwriting the current line.

Does anybody know where the problem comes from? I really need to see the output of my `build` script, so there's no way I could just add a "undo" command after my bind, that would simply erase the inserted output of my command.

FWIW, I'm running MacVim snapshot 63 on OSX 10.7.2, but it also occurs when I use the plain old command-line `vim` (v7.3) from iTerm2 (1.0.0.20111020).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
map <silent> <F5> :lcd /my/script/directory \| !./build debug<CR>
```

The escaped pipe is here to chain commands.

Comment: Yay! thanks, you saved my day. Didn't know that you could pipe Vim commands, too.

Comment: You could also just insert a `:` after the first `<CR>`. Without it you are telling vim to filter current line with the external command and read back its output.

Comment: @Cyrille: you don't pipe Vim commands, you chain them. The `|` operator in VimL is equivalent to `&&` in a Unix shell.

Comment: @mMontu: that's what Birei suggested below. As I answered, I tried it and it didn't work (at least in MacVim).

Comment: @Benoit: thanks for the clarification. That's what I felt right after posting my comment, it's not like a unix pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon before `!`, like:

```
map <F5> :lcd /my/script/directory<CR>:! ./build debug<CR>
```